# adding additional targets to iphone app

Tags: iphone

How does one add additional targets to an iphone application?

I would like to add the following targets: CFNetwork.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework and libz.1.2.3.dylib to my app to be able to use twit pic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean adding these frameworks to your xCode project ?

Just do a right clic on the Frameworks folder, "Add", "Add an existing Framework". :-)

And don't forget to #import the frameworks in the file which need them !